# Body stop scrolling after keydown, keypress with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, keypress

I have some scrolling actions after keydown, keypress pressing. So this is what it looks like:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        // some scrolling actions in specifie div
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        // some scrolling actions in specifie div
    }
});
```

Everithing is working fine but when im scrolling, keypressing with my div scrolls also whole page. Is there any option to stop this body scrolling?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `.preventDefault()` in there...

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(40);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(38);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If your body is what currently has the scrolling animation then use `stop()`. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$('body').stop();
```

Comment: It's not an animation - it's the default behaviour of pressing up or down on a page.