# Prevent Scrolling in HTML5

Tags: css, html, scroll, viewport

I would like to prevent all forms of page scrolling in my `HTML5` application. I have tried searching on SO and [Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=html5%20prevent%20scrolling&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for a general answer for *Prevent all scrolling mechanisms*, but everything is very specific - like how to disable scrolling with touches, or with [arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901273/javascript-prevent-scrolling), or the scrollbars themselves.

The reason I am looking for this is to be able to create a new `div` below the visible screen, and animate it up (and down. This [MoonBase](http://moonbase.com/PhDBrown/1) shows what I mean.), and I don't want the user to be able to scroll down to see it. Is this possible? Is there a `meta` tag I can set? Or `CSS`? - Or, am I taking the wrong approach to my animation? That is, would all my problems be fixed if I simply animated in from the side instead (and included the `meta` tag `width=device-width`)? Is that the closest way for me to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript, just use CSS. Set `overflow: hidden;`:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just found this out with a little more searching. I will mark answered when I can.

Comment: It's still possible to scroll using keys when you do this. Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/ETBq2/

Comment: @romkyns is there any way to stop that?

Comment: @Tim yes, via JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916620/disable-arrow-key-scrolling-in-users-browser

Comment: @dersvenhesse that would work, except the problem is using the middle click scroll, not arrow keys - see this meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243748

Comment: How do I do that without cutting the content?

Comment: But what if you need `overflow: auto`? It's useful for getting divs to expand to the height of floats.